# Cannot start Sinatra on a port specified in a file

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I have a Sinatra app which I want to run on a port specified by parameters in a file. I'm using mixlib/config project to define the config file and read from it. I'm unable to start Sinatra on a port specified in the file.

Inside the main class I have:

```
class Api < Sinatra::Base
  base = Base.new
  opts = Hash.new
  @@redis = Redis.new(:host=> opts[:host], :port => opts[:port])

  some methods
   ..
   ...

  set :bind, '0.0.0.0'
  set :port, opts[:sinatra_port]  --> This does not substitute the value from the file. I need to be able to pass the port as a parameter in the file. 

  some routes..
  .
  .
  run!

end
```

The config file has the following:

```
host '10.199.4.76'
port '6379'
sinatra_port 9494
```

When starting with `ruby api.rb`, it starts WEBricks on port 8080 and not 9494 which is defined in the config file.

Can someone point out what I'm missing here?

Comment: Not sure but shouldn't be port a int? so something like `opts[:sinatra_port].to_i`

Comment: @Sirl33tname No, does not help..it basically converts it to an int and the port number is basically not want is in the config file.